# Rails 7 SassC Error: Bootstrap not found or unreadable while uploading on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, asset-pipeline, ruby-on-rails-7

I am upgrading my app from Rails 6.1 to Rails 7.

While testing it on development env., it works fine.
But I encouter an issue while uploading it on heroku.

Heroku raise this error while precompiling assets :

```
Running: rake assets:precompile

rake aborted!

SassC::SyntaxError: Error: File to import not found or unreadable: ../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.

on line 7:1 of app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss

>> @import "../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

I've been trying many solutions from stackoverflow and ChatGPT :

- Updating Gems with Bundle update / Bundle install
- Updating 'bootstrap' gem
- updating the path of bootstrap import line in my css file
- clearing temp files
- updating sassc
- upgrading yarn | uninstalling/reinstalling boostratp with yarn
- reinstalling dependencies with npm